# Arduino and Processing (PDE) via Ethernet

Tags: arduino, processing, ethernet, pde

**Arduino: Is it possible to communicate with Arduino through Ethernet, using a [Processing](http://www.processing.org) (PDE) script?**

I've already created a desktop application using Processing, but in this case I communicate with Arduino through the USB.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can
You could for example create an arduino chat server : http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ChatServer
And create a processing client like this : http://processing.org/reference/libraries/net/Client_write_.html

ofcourse you would need to change the 
`myClient = new Client(this, "127.0.0.1", 10002);` 

to

`myClient = new Client(this, "IP of Arduino", 23);`

If you would then connect with a telnet session to the arduin o you would see output from the prosessing script comming back from the arduino